# ProPublica Congressional API CiviCRM Module

Tags: civicrm-entity

Until 2014 there was active development on the Sunlight Congress API and there was and is a CiviCRM module that uses the Sunlight Congress API to make Congress data available to CiviCRM.

ProPublica has taken over development of the Sunlight Congress API and merged it with it's own [Congress API](https://projects.propublica.org/api-docs/congress-api/#overview)

Is anyone planning to update the CiviCRM Sunlight Congress API module to work with the ProPublica [Congress API](https://projects.propublica.org/api-docs/congress-api/#overview) module so that CiviCRM maintains the ability to link to information about the activities of Congress?

Answer (score 3):

The successor to the Sunlight API Dupal module is the Civi-native [Electoral API extension](https://github.com/josephlacey/coop.palantetech.electoral).  I wrote documentation back when I was collaborating on the project, but it seems to have been taken down.  I will investigate finding a copy and getting it online.

You may also be interested in the [CiviCRM for e-advocacy](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/Using+CiviCRM+for+e-advocacy) page.